# Why Time difference gives me 2 different results

Tags: javascript, time, datediff

this code should give 0:40 minutes, however in one way gives me 0:20 minutes, and in the other way gives me 1:40 minutes.

```
var t1 = '12:05'.split(':'),
    t2 = '12:45'.split(':');

var d1 = new Date(0,0,0,t1[0],t1[1]),
    d2 = new Date(0,0,0,t2[0],t2[1]);

document.write(d1+'<BR>');
document.write(d2+'<BR>');

var d = new Date(d1-d2);
// should give 0:40 minutes
document.write(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + '<BR>');
// 0:20 minutes
var d = new Date(d2-d1);
document.write(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + '<BR>');
// 1:40 minutes
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because date subtraction is not commutative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function to calculate two dates difference and show the result in HH:MM format.

Because Javascript returns two date difference in timestamp & if we use that timestamp to get JS date object it creates totally new date.

Here is the sample dateDiff function :

```
function dateDiff(){
    var start = '12:05'.split(':'), // hardcoded value for sample
    end = '12:45'.split(':');      // you can pass start and end value as parameter to dateDiff function.

    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);

    return ( (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting two dates gives you the number of milliseconds between them. Passing this to `new Date` gives you a new date object that many milliseconds from epoch.

If you want the number of minutes between two dates, just do this:

```
(d1-d2)/(60*1000);
```